# Calling a string from a separate file

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

What I need to do is to call a string from a separate file. The problem is that I need to able to have the number in the string as a variable or an argument as the string is a CSS Selector I need to locate an element with.

Here is the whole string: 'a_very_long_css_(1)_selector'

```
def string_create(x):
    example_string = 'a_very_long_css_('
    example_string = example_string + str(x)
    example_string = example_string + ')selector'
```

Now if go to separate file I need to call this string like that:

```
driver.find.element_by_css_selector(string_create(5)).click()
```

Unfortunately a function cannot be a selector in that case.

Comment: How you extract string from file and how extracted string looks like?

Comment: Are you actually returning example_string from that function?

Comment: Returning the string in the funciton was what was missing. Thank you.